# Animated TV series with King Arthur / Sword in Stone theme; 'Excalibur' replaced by AI robot scepter

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for an animated TV series which was probably made in the late 90s or early 2000s.

I seem to remember the setting is roughly medieval, except there are also elements of futuristic technology. The main theme of the story has a sort of King Arthur vibe in the sense that the hero is destined to save the kingdom.

The one distinctive thing that I remember for certain is that the central weapon/item of the main character is an artificially intelligent metal staff. Its head is an orb with a glowing yellow bulb or 'eye' on it (not unlike the appearance of the Starkiller Base from Star Wars: The Force Awakens). The shaft of the staff tapers down to a point, which can be plugged into sockets on various devices throughout the world to power or control them. Again with the King Arthur vibe I recall that this staff is his 'Excalibur' - it is implied that he is somehow destined to have it. Either its power or the knowledge contained within its AI is notably unique in-universe. When not doing anything exciting the main character often wore the staff slung over his back on a strap. It did have a voice and often spoke but I can't remember anything about its personality.

Sadly I can't remember any more details about the overarching plot or any of the other characters but I'm hoping this robotic mcguffin is unique enough that somebody recognises it.

Editing as requested:
I watched the show in English (I am fairly confident it has a Western / non-Anime origin). I watched it broadcast free-to-air on NZ television probably in the early 2000s

Comment: Hi there,  Just a couple of questions, and you can edit the answers into the body, if you have them- what language was it in and where did you watch it?  Do you remember if it was network or cable?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for "xyber 9". THeres plenty of it floating about on youtube.....

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much