# Cartoon about Excalibur

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Around 2008 I remember I saw a short/pilot for a show about the King Arthur mythos that involved a shapeshifting Excalibur sword on Cartoon Network. It had a slick design similar to *Samurai Jack*. Some of the only things I recall was a white horse and a scene where the main group is falling and the main character morphs Excalibur into a chain weapon and saves everyone.

Comment: @Valentiene, does the tone of the show was serious or comedy?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur_(TV_series)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150976/animated-tv-series-with-king-arthur-sword-in-stone-theme-excalibur-replaced/150977?